# How to simplify a regular expression by not re-writing the same capture group?

Tags: javascript, regex

*Input text:*

**Monday to Friday** 6:00 a.m. to 8:00 p.m.

**Saturday to Sunday** 6:30 a.m. to 8:00 p.m.

*I need to match the bold text so the following regex:*

```
(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday) (to) (Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)
```

How can I simplify the regular expression by avoiding re-writing the `(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)` capture group twice?

Comment: What engine are you implementing this in?

Comment: I'm using Javascript

Comment: You would have to leave the pure regex mechanisms and use features of the surrounding language, e.g. parts of the regex in a textual variable. Would that be an option?

Comment: Well, yes. I could `let captureGroup = (Monday|Tuesday...)` and do `let regex = captureGroup + ' (to) ' + captureGroup` but I was looking for a regex mechanism

Comment: If you don't need the individual captures, and the pattern must occur at the start of the input, then you could do `^(( to |^)(Monday|Tuesday)){2}`

Comment: @trincot yeah this will work +1

Comment: In Perl, you could use `my $rx1 = qr/(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)/; my $rx2 = qr/\b$rx1\s+to\s+$rx1\b/;` which saves you writing the long expression twice, but simply embeds it twice in the operational regex, which you might use with `while (<>)
{
    print "$1 - $2\n" if m/$rx2/;
}`.  That prints `Monday - Friday` and `Saturday - Sunday` on two lines for the sample data in the question.

Comment: With PCRE your can use `(?group_number)` to repeat the pattern defined in a group [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CywZwL/1). Unfortunatly, it doesn't work with javascript

Answer (score 1):

You may define a string fragment alternation, and then reuse it:

```js
var input = "Monday to Friday 6:00 a.m. to 8:00 p.m.";
var alt = "(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)";
var re = new RegExp("^" + alt + " (to) " + alt + ".*$");
if (re.test(input)) {
    console.log("valid");
}
else {
    console.log("invalid");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, like I said in the comment I was looking for a regex mechanism. So if there isn't any I'll resort to this

Comment: `like I said` is incorrect English grammar, unless you are telling me that you just said "like."  You mean to say "as I said."

Comment: LOL totally irrelevant but OK and I've been using that phrase all my life. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/like-i-say-said

Comment: ..aand there's this http://www.quodb.com/search/%22like%20i%20said%22
and yes I know I can't begin a sentence with "and"

Comment: And what makes you think there's a rule against starting sentences with "And"? As Churchill (reputedly) said, ["this is the kind of nonsense up with which I will not put"](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9Rk0Vc-ONUC&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=%22this+is+the+kind+of+nonsense+up+with+which+I+will+not+put%22&source=bl&ots=3zwrarVBei&sig=ACfU3U1XGyo2gd68cRRK7FaqxUxa_7SzHw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifz_aOhOPgAhVsU98KHZZQDdQQ6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage). And "like I said" is perfectly idiomatic English English — a little informal, perhaps, but not incorrect. I don't understand American enough to pontificate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Like is a preposition, and an adverb is really required here.  But none of that matters now, because in the future we will all being using Grammarly.

Answer (score 1):

If the following assumptions can be made:

- You don't need the individual captures after the match was made
- The pattern must occur at the *start* of the input

Then you could do:

[`^\b(( to |^)(Monday|Tuesday)){2}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/d92Ssa/4)

#### Explanation

- `^` matches with the start of the input.
- `\b` requires the first character to be a word-character. It is there to prevent matching " to " at the start of the string.
- `{2}` requires the main part to match twice in a row
- `( to |^)` can in theory match with either " to " or the start of the input, but since the first time we know we are at the start (because of the first `^`), and it cannot match " to " because of the previous `\b`, it is a no-operation then. The second time, it cannot match with the start of the input anymore, since we then already matched one day, so only " to " can match on the second iteration.
- `\b` at the end is there to avoid that something like `Tuesdaymorning` would match.

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter, but also uglier:

```
((?:(?:Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day)(?: to )?)+
```

Although it matches something like `Monday Friday` as well (without the `to`).

I would definitely stay with the bigger version myself, for the sake of readability.

Comment: Note that this could match " to " twice, as in "**Monday to Friday to** work"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your search text contains data only in format : 
Day to day  6:00 a.m. to 8:00 p.m,  You can use

```
re.findall("([A-Za-z]*day)\s(to)\s([A-Za-z]+day)","Monday to Tuesday  6:00 a.m. to 8:00 p.m")
```